# Generating a query to find records containing specified character

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project. From the given list, I want to retrieve all the Courses that start with a `1` (basically, Year 1 Courses).

[image]

For example, I would like

```
ELEC ENG 1100 Analog Electronics
ENG 1001 Introduction to Engineering
MATHS 1011 Mathematics IA
```

And not

```
COMP SCI 2201 Algorithm & Data Structure Analysis
COMP SCI 3001 Computer Networks & Applications
```

(even they contain `1` in them, but not in the starting position).

I have stored my Course names as one string. How could I go about querying this? I tried

```
Course.where("name LIKE '%1%'")
```

and this returns all the Courses that contain `1` in them. But this is not what I want. How could I generate a query for what I require?

Comment: `name LIKE '% 1%'` is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The logic of SQL behind your query is

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('ELEC ENG 1100 Analog Electronics'),
    ('ENG 5001 Introduction to Engineering'),
    ('COMP SCI 2201 Algorithm & Data Structure Analysis'),
    ('MATHS 1011 Mathematics IA')
)t(topic)
WHERE SUBSTRING(topic,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',topic)),1) = 1
```

If someone could translate to ruby-on-rail

Comment: `PATINDEX` is RDBMS specific function. For example, PostgreSQL or SQLite haven't it. OP didn't specify RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Let's define required character (integer to be more precise)

```rb
course_year = 1
```

If course year follows after white space, you can build such pattern

```rb
Course.where("name LIKE ?", "% #{course_year}%")
Course.where("name ~ ?", " #{course_year}") # works in PostgreSQL
```

Comment: These can both be converted to more agnostic forms via `Course.arel_table[:name].matches("% #{course_year}%")` and `Course.arel_table[:name].matches_regexp(" #{course_year}")`. Note: the latter is not supported by SQLite or the MSSQL adapters.